# Why it prints unexpected values?

Tags: c++, class, object

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class calculator {
public:
    int n1, n2;

    friend void setNumbers(calculator v);
    friend void getNumbers(calculator v);
};

void setNumbers(calculator v) {
    cin >> v.n1 >> v.n2;
}

void getNumbers(calculator v) {
    cout << v.n1 << ' ' << v.n2 << '\n';
}

int main() {
    calculator calc;
    setNumbers(calc);
    getNumbers(calc);
    return 0;
}
```

When I call getNumbers function, it prints totally different values which I didn't input. For example when I input `3 6`, it prints `0 1`, while I expected `3 6`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Important reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: @user4581301 I tried to add the calculator &v, it gives me error.

Comment: Why are your functions `friend`s instead of usual member functions?

Comment: Perhaps you added it to one declaration of each function instead of both. It's as good a guess as any.

Comment: @chris Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the object without a reference won't change the values of your calculator object when you expect them to be initialized by your input values after a call to `setNumbers`. Instead they'll have garbage values since they are not initialized for `getNumbers`.

Pass the calculator objects via reference by using `&` as mentioned in the comments and you're good to go.

```cpp
class calculator 
{
    public:
    int n1, n2;
    friend void setNumbers(calculator &v);
    friend void getNumbers(calculator &v);

};

void setNumbers(calculator &v) {
    cin >> v.n1 >> v.n2;
}

void getNumbers(calculator &v) {
    cout << v.n1 << ' ' << v.n2 << '\n';
}
```